# In Unreal4, Can I use switch case in C++ with FString?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, xml

I'm making XML parsing code with FXmlNode. I want to iterate through GetChildrenNodes(), and use switch-case with FString which is return value of FXmlNode::GetTag(). Is there someway to do that? Or should I use

```
 if (Tag == TEXT("XX") .. else if (Tag == TEXT("YY"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: switch cases in c++ only support primatives (ints, chars, etc) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings

Comment: @CobaltHex That's right. I wander if I can get some kind of hash value from FString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you can't switch on strings, only integers (and the values you compare to must be constant).

But it is possible to *indirectly* switch on strings by choosing a stable mapping from string to integer (such as a hash function), applying that to the constants as well as the string to switch on, and using that. Because the expression in a `case` statement must be a compile-time constant, you're likely going to want to write that hash or mapping yourself and not rely on anything Unreal provides, as it may not be sufficient for this purpose.

[FNV1a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) is a simple, decent hash function, and [can be implemented as a `constexpr` function](https://gist.github.com/underscorediscovery/81308642d0325fd386237cfa3b44785c) in C++. This will let you write:

```
constexpr std::uint32_t fnv1a(const char* s) { ... };

...

switch(fnv1a(someString)) {
  case fnv1a("Foo"): ... break;
  case fnv1a("Bar"): ... break;
  default: ... break;
}
```

If you don't have a modern C++ compiler, you will be forced to manually hash the strings yourself and write the resulting constant values in the `case` statements, which is exceedingly cumbersome.

Frankly, I'd argue that if the comparison code in question isn't a performance bottleneck, you're better off not overcomplicating things and just doing `if`/`else` chains. If it *is* a performance bottleneck, it might be worth revisiting whether or not you can replace the strings in a broader, algorithmic sense as it will likely be a bigger performance win.

As always, your mileage may vary, and you'll want to engage the services of a profiler to ensure you're actually gaining something by adding this extra layer of indirection.

Comment: Perhaps use an enum instead? If you are using XML, your set of strings should be known and well-formed, right?